# Why do Azure Visual Studio Team Services VSTS build fail?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have a build that is failing after about 15 minutes.

This is the error.

> The job has been abandoned because agent Hosted Agent did not renew
>   the lock. Ensure agent is running, not sleeping, and has not lost
>   communication with the service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with TFS 2015 and it seems that the real error is written in _diag folder of the build agent (check the log file that was modified at the same time when the error occurred).

In my case it was a network issue.